# Mocking Entity Framework Core context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to test my app so I need to mock my EF context.

My code seems to be ok, but I have following exception:

> "System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source"

Here is my test method:

```
  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProductContext>().Options;
    var settings = new SqlSettings
    {
        InMemory = true
    };

    var context = new Mock<ProductContext>(options, settings);
    var mockTreeService = new TreeService(context.Object);
    await mockTreeService.CreateTreeAsync("Testing tree", Guid.NewGuid());

    context.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Tree>(), CancellationToken.None), Times.Once);
```

It looks like that this exception is thrown during executing this piece of code

```
            var tree = await _context.Trees
                .Include(x => x.Translation)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Translation.Pl == name);
```

It comes from my service which I'm testing

Comment: In my opinion "include" makes probles, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: You may find the [EF Core Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/) docs useful.

Comment: You don't need to mock ProductContext in EF core, instead use InMemory ProductContext

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think this is due to not having a connection string set. Frankly, it's a bit difficult to fully mock out `DbContext`, which is why the EF Core team has provided an in-memory implementation. This is far easier to work with for testing purposes. Just change your `options` initialization to:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProductContext>()
                  .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                  .Options;
```

Afterwards, you'll need to populate the database with your test data. Then, you can run the rest of your test.

*Note: if you're using the in-memory database, you don't need to mock the context anymore, so you can remove that bit of code. The in-memory database is essentially, itself, a mock.*

Comment: I am using in memory database. It is set in Product Context by passing sql settings in construcor

Comment: No. You're setting `InMemory` to true, which honestly, I think is only there for SQLite. That's *not* the same thing. You need to use `UseInMemoryDatabase(string)`.

Comment: Are you sure that I'am not using InMemoryDatabase?
My code from ProductContext:
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
  if (_settings.InMemory) //Setting injecten in constructor
   {
          optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
  }
    }

Formatted code ->
https://pastebin.com/0x794fJG

Comment: If i remove mockCtx = new Moq<ProductContext>(options, settings), and leave only mockCtx = new ProductContext(options, settings) it works, but I need to use moq.

Comment: Why do you need to use a mock? You set up the starting state of the DB, perform some action and check the state afterwards. If the state is what it should be after the op, then the test passes. The fact that it calls one method or another on the context is an *implementation* detail, and doesn't matter from a testing perspective. You test results not implementation.

Comment: For example to use Verify method from Moq

Comment: Again, implementation detail. You should not be testing that in this scenario, anyways. If the underlying logic changes, your test will fail, even though the result remains the same. That's a bad test.

Comment: Had to include a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory in my test project !!

Comment: Microsoft recommends that you do not use In-Memory database for testing but instead use the repository pattern to wrap the context. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy#inmemory-as-a-database-fake  I'm not sure I completely agree with Microsoft on this one.  I've used both In-Memory database and MOQ on an IDbContext which are essentially the same and they work well.  The repository wrapped around the context does help abstract the EF Core but it's redundant and costly to maintain.  My 2 cents: For simple database access tests, use the In-Memory database

Answer (score 6):

I have used this https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock library. Very easy and can write unit test using less coding.

You can use most of Moq methods if you are using moq framework.

Below is example code for test DBQuerys.

```
public async Task<Boat> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    => await _boatContext.Boats.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

[Fact]
public async Task GetByIdAsync_WhenCalled_ReturnsItem()
{
    // Arrange
    var models = new[] { new Boat { id = "p1" } };
    var dbContextMock = new DbContextMock<BoatContext>();
    dbContextMock.CreateDbQueryMock(x => x.Boats, models);

    var service = new Properties(dbContextMock.Object);

    // Act
    var okResult = await service.GetByIdAsync("p1");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<Boat>(okResult.Result);
}
```

Posting here this may help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my Moq/NSubstitute extension MockQueryable: https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable
supported all Sync/Async operations

```
//1 - create a List<T> with test items
var users = new List<UserEntity>()
{
 new UserEntity,
 ...
};

//2 - build mock by extension
var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMock();

//3 - setup the mock as Queryable for Moq
_userRepository.Setup(x => x.GetQueryable()).Returns(mock.Object);

//3 - setup the mock as Queryable for NSubstitute
_userRepository.GetQueryable().Returns(mock);
```

DbSet also supported

```
//2 - build mock by extension
var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();

//3 - setup DbSet for Moq
var userRepository = new TestDbSetRepository(mock.Object);

//3 - setup DbSet for NSubstitute
var userRepository = new TestDbSetRepository(mock);
```

**Note:**

- AutoMapper supported from 1.0.4 ver
- DbQuery supported from 1.1.0 ver

Comment: I tried your NuGet package, but I don't see any way to do more complex setups. I need to test a query with joins, and I don't see how to tell your package that there is more than one mocked DbSet involved. (Just came here to find an alternative for your package, so happy to see you here.)

Comment: @KlomDark thank you for your feedback. It very sad for me to see that you was not able to use MockQueryable to test your code. I'm working on the project to make it better. If you see that MockQueryable doesn't have required for you functionality, you can create an issue on GitHub page with detailed description. Pull requests with new features from you are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's correct to `Mock` the `DbContext`. You should be `mocking` your `repositories` in your testing... `mocking` the `DbContext` is you basically testing `Microsoft's` code... which is dumb because they already do that. So again... all of your data access should go through `repositories` (see [Repository Pattern](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/)) and you should be `mocking` those in your testing, not the `DbContext`.

Comment: It's generally true that testing code-off-the-shelf, especially from a distributor like Microosoft is wasteful. In the case of entity framework though, there are huge benefits because you gain the ability to test your configuration.

Comment: That's incorrect, you should still be testing your configuration through your repositories.

Comment: I am not saying you shouldn't. I am saying mocking the dbcontext, when done correctly, can help you test `joins`, `relationships` and such configuration. Which is very useful.

Comment: And I am saying no, you should not be testing your `joins` or `relationships` directly via the`dbcontext` but instead test them through your `repositories`

Comment: My goodness... All I am saying is... This is a good idea - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory. It's okay if you still don't agree. My opinion. I never said or insinuated that you test anything outside of your repos; I am suggesting you test your repos by mocking your DbContext. Mocking your dbcontext has worked for me with code-first. Don't agree? Sorry I can't help to convince you. Just my opinion. Btw, when I say Repo, I don't mean your DbContext class. I mean the direct consumer of your context. It translates between your storage and your 'domain'

Comment: The point of the repository pattern is to handle the persistence layer for your domain. EF already does that. Wrapping a repository around EF is redundant and useless. Choosing EF or any other ORM is opting to use a third-party DAL instead of writing your own. If you're going to write your own anyway, then dump EF and just got straight SQL. At least there'd be some point to it, then, and your app would probably be easier to maintain and more efficient as a result.

Comment: @chris-pratt I hope we never have to work together. Your idea is the dumbest thing I've heard in a long time.

Comment: Feeling's mutual, if you think so, because I'd hate to maintain your rats nest of pointless code.

Comment: I dont want to reignite a previous debate, but I *do* see the value in mocking your context. When the context behaves in a certain way, you want your repository to behave a certain way. One way to make sure your repository is "reacting" correctly to the context, is to mock how the context acts. You can set up the context to do whatever, and be sure your repository does what you want it to do in that scenario.

Comment: You might need to mock your repository or DbContext if they are dependencies of the code under test. It doesn't really matter if it is a repository or DbContext, it is a dependency and this is why you need to mock it.

Comment: No, none of those reasons are valid. If you are mocking your `DbContext` then you really just don't know what you're doing.

Comment: In the real world most people do not implement the Repository Pattern. The question does not relate to testing Entity Framework, instead it's relates to mocking it's output which is used for other business logic that will be tested. So there are real use-cases for mocking EF.

Comment: No, you should never have to test a third-party library. I don't know where you get your stats about who uses which patterns, but I would say that for most use cases  the `repository pattern` is the best choice for data access, and only in some more rare cases should other patterns be considered.