# Can you use FakeItEasy with EF Core

Tags: .net-core, in-memory-database, ef-core-2.0, fakeiteasy

I am wondering if I can use FakeItEasy with EF Core? I need to write some unit tests around CRUD operations. Can someone provide some insight into whether I should use In memory database or FakeItEasy? Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Definetely In-Memory database. Or if you want test some relational database features then you can use "in-memory" SQLite. You don't want to mock EntityFramework, because it would be testing your implementation details, where every time you change a query, without changing behaviour, you will need rewrite your tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking Entity Framework Core context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553878/mocking-entity-framework-core-context)

Comment: Technically, you can mock it (most methods in `DbSet<T>` are virtual), but it's difficult to setup. Use in memory database, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554912/98713

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look my [MockQueryable](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable) package. It supports FakeItEasy.

Simple example:

```
 //1 - create a List<T> with test items
 var users = new List<UserEntity>()
 {
   new UserEntity{LastName = "ExistLastName", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/20/2012")},
   ...
 };
 
 //2 - build mock by extension
 var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMock();
 
 //3 - setup the mock as Queryable for FakeItEasy
 A.CallTo(() => userRepository.GetQueryable()).Returns(mock);
```

[Here](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/blob/master/src/MockQueryable/MockQueryable.Sample/MyServiceFakeItEasyTests.cs) you can find more examples of usage MockQueryable + FakeItEasy