Mocking EF DBContext with Moq C#
I am attempting to mock a DB context to use in testing with NUnit. I keep getting either

OneTimeSetUp: System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of
class: Tracker.Models.TrackerContext.TrackerContext.

Or

OneTimeSetUp: Moq.MockException : ImisContext.TrackerOrderBridges =
InternalDbSet<TrackerOrderBridge> invocation failed with mock
behavior Strict.   All invocations on the mock must have a
corresponding setup.

I know nothing is wrong with the TrackerContext as I'm using it the same way in another test class just missing the iMIS Context in the controller aswell. The TrackerContext is created code first way with iConfig. Whereas the iMIS context uses a scaffold so base:options etc
When i use MockBehaviour.Strict it gives the second error. Without it displays the first one but again I know nothing is wrong with the TrackerContext. Without trying the new Enquiry Controller section the test doesnt fail either, only when its being accessed in there.
public EnquiryControllerTests()
{
    _mockTrackerContext = new Mock<TrackerContext>(Mock.Of<IConfiguration>());
    _mockiMISContext = new Mock<ImisContext>(new DbContextOptions<ImisContext>());
    _mockActiveDirectoryHelper = new Mock<ActiveDirectoryHelper>(Mock.Of<IHttpContextAccessor>());
    _mockEmailHelper = new Mock<EmailHelper>();

    _enquiryController = new EnquiryController(
        _mockiMISContext.Object,
        _mockTrackerContext.Object,
        _mockActiveDirectoryHelper.Object,
        _mockEmailHelper.Object
    );
}

Tried all different ways to get the options in the context. But I am not sure what error means I'm getting closer and which one is at the start.
EDIT
Tried with a few of the other controllers and they worked. Found out the issue is actually with the setup of the EmailHelper Mock.

When looking to unit test code that accesses EF it helps to use a thin abstraction such as a Repository that exposes data via IQueryable. Alternatively there are packages you can add  to your unit test projects with mockable proxies for the EF DbContext and DbSets. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore) Note that if you are using async methods you may also need something like MockQueryable. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.4-beta)

Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553878/mocking-entity-framework-core-context? Seems to be pretty identicial to yours, IMHO.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Using InMemoryDatabase is not a correct solution! As far as I remember it doesn't allow grouping on server side so queries that I optimized to run perfectly on SQLServer failed on it. I ended up having to use TestContainers but they are super slow. This way I had to move most of the testing from unit tests to e2e tests.
